# Load Curve from file instead using Content Manager

Tags: xna, curve

I'm looking to load a Curve file in XNA but not through the content manager process e.g. Load("").

Is there any way to do this?

For example:

Curve curve = new Curve("filename"); or
Curve curve = Curve.FromFile("filename"); // similar to loading texture2d and song.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to do it through the content pipeline? Without using it, you would simply have to create & write functionality that the content processor already has/does.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the additional work of maintaining content pipeline projects across several platforms. It appears other content types can be loaded from a stream, just seemed odd that curve doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating curve data in xml form and building/importing it using the content processor will work (and the easiest way to go) for PC, win7phone, & xb360. If you are planning more platforms than that, then yes, you would have to write your own.